# How to send object to Service in android

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I want to send YouTubePlayer object to my Service via intent. Here is code how I send YouTubePlayer object to my service, but it gives error. How can I solve it ? Please help.

***java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.player.a cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable***

MainActivity.java

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mYouTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
    mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(new YouTubePlayerInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitSuccess(@NonNull final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
             youTubePlayer.addListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onReady() {
                     startService(youTubePlayer);
                 }
             });
        }
    },true);
}


private void startService(YouTubePlayer player)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExampleService.class);
    intent.putExtra("player", (Parcelable) player);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Service class

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {
YouTubePlayer mYouTubePlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mYouTubePlayer = intent.getParcelableExtra("player");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    mYouTubePlayer.loadVideo("mHM5zyRZqpw",0);

    Intent main_intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,main_intent,0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example service")
            .setContentText("Content text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Stop service", pi)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);


    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Put your class `YouTubePlayer`, please

Comment: I have only MainActivity.java class and Service.java class, YouTubePlayer is You Tube API library